# Vuetify v-select get item index

Tags: vue.js

is there a way to get the item-value by not using the v-model in v-select...
Here is my code.

```
<v-flex xl4 lg4 md4 sm6 xs12 class="pa-2" v-for="(question, i) in questions" :key="i">
        <v-select
            :label="question.name"
            :items="question.answers"
            item-value="id"
            item-text="name"
            @change="addAnswer(i)"
            required
          ></v-select>
  </v-flex>
```

I can't used a `v-model` since it is a loop. I can passed the `i` in the loop for the question but how about the item-value?

Methods:

```
addAnswer(i){

        this.questionAnswer.push({
          questionId: i,
          answerId: 'this should be answer Id'
        })
        console.log(this.questionAnswer)

  }
```

If you have any idea how to do this... It would be a great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@change="addAnswer"` will pass to the `addAnswer` method the selected value.

So you don't have to pass the index.Anyway i made an example to see my way of solution.It needs more code to be perfect,but i think it may help you.

[See it in action here](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/fg461d55/1/)

Comment: Thanks... how I miss the `@change="addAnswer(question)"` but anyway thanks for the letting me know that I don't need to passed the `question`.... it works like a charm. Thank you..