# get complete Vuetify item from v-autocomplete

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete, vuetify.js

I need to get the entire array element that makes up the Autocomplete item, I want the element so I can store it in Veux without store each item, such as first name, MI last name etc.  I'm going to build upon another question that was very similar that was posted here [Vuetify v-select get item index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50089729/vuetify-v-select-get-item-index)  and with the jsfiddle answer solution

my code that I'm using is:

```
            <v-list-tile>
      <v-autocomplete
        v-model="data"
        :allow-overflow="false"
        :items="named_items"
        :item-text="getFullName"
        :loading="loadingMembers"
        :debounce-search="0"
        :search-input.sync="searchInput"
        class="purple-input search-input"
        default
        color="purple"
        autofocus
        placeholder="Search..."
        item-value="MemberID"
        hide-no-data
        no-data-text="Add New Member"
        @change="changeMember"
        @keyup.enter="hitEnter"
      />
    </v-list-tile>
```

the jsfiddle is at   https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/fg461d55/1/

and my question is when an item is selected is it possible to get the element that makes up the ID, Question and Answers? so the it can be stored as an array?

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible, for example, you have already bound to events, but you can have the name or values of their targets.

[See: Method Event handlers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers)